# In maven, what is the name for the combination of group id, artifact id and version?

Tags: maven, terminology

I am looking for the official terminology for the concept that comprises these 3 fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's referred to as the "GAV" (groupId, artifactId, version), or, more rarely, "coordinates".

Comment: Accepted because of mentioning the short naming GAV :)

Answer (score 2):

After searching around for a bit longer, it seems like its called the 'coordinate': https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates

Although the coordinate may comprise additional fields, I suppose this might be as specific as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's the identity of an artifact.